# ScatterLayout with boundries

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a layout that will allow me to zoom in and out and navigate through its content. Very much like a browser on android where you can zoom in to articles and navigate through the paragraphs.

Sadly couldn't find something like that in Kivy.

I found the ScatterLayout class and this code: https://github.com/melissadale/Learning-Kivy/commit/0a3298ef767526ea905e1ae1099686f7f40ff08b which allows to zoom in, by scaling the widgets (This code definitely needs improvements).
The problem is that the widgets within the layout are growing and exceeding  its boundaries.
I need to find a way to show only the part of those widgets that is within the boundaries of the layout.

any ideas?